# what does clang command option -lm mean?

Tags: clang

I found someone says that `-lm` means linking to the math library.
I want to figure out the meaning by using `build-in help` in the terminal.
So I run the `$ clang --help`
I don't find any stuff related to `-l` or `-m`
How can I get the meaning of `-lm` with the self-help terminal?

Comment: Unfortunately clang doesn't seem to have documentation for `-l`. But `clang` tries to imitate `gcc` with its command line syntax and options, and gcc does document it: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options

Answer (score 6):

The -l{name} flag tells the linker to link against lib{name}. So -lm links against libm, the c math library.
This isn't a flag to the clang compiler but passed to the linker, which is why you won't find it with `clang --help` or `man clang`.
If you run clang with the `--verbose` flag you will see the invocation of the linker (in my case `/usr/bin/ld`) as the last step.
By running `man ld` or `ld --help` (or whichever linker your clang version is using) you will find the documentation.
 Keep in mind that not all flags are passed to the linker in this way (-l is probably passed for compatibility with the gcc compiler as [melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52029857/what-does-clang-command-option-lm-mean/52030015#comment91010431_52029857) said). To make sure an option is passed, use the `-Wl` option of clang.